# Cant Deserialize json string with JavaScriptSerializer

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, webmethod

From javascript I sent to a webmethod the following :

```
            var firstname = $("#txtfirstname").val();
            var lastname = $("#txtlastname").val();

            var dataFilter = { "filterType": "fn_ln", "data": { "firstName": firstname, "lastName": lastname } }
            var data = JSON.stringify(dataFilter)
            data = data.replace(/\"/g, '\'');
            datatoSend = '{ filters:"' + data + '" }';
```

I use `data.replace(/\"/g, '\'');` so the webmethod can accepts the data(without that I get an error 500 from webmethod)

Once in the web method I receive

```
"{'filterType':'fn_ln','data':{'firstName':' aa','lastName':' bb'}}"
```

as the parameter. Then with c#, when I try.

```
JavaScriptSerializer sr = new JavaScriptSerializer();
srFilterData filterin = sr.Deserialize<srFilterData>(filters);
```

I get an error saying that `No parameterless constructor defined for type of 'System.String[]`

This is my class:

```
 [Serializable]
    public class srFilterData
    {
        public String filterType { get; set; }
        public String data { get; set; }
    }
```

Whats the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your C# class as follows:

```
[Serializable]
public class srFilterData
{
    public String filterType { get; set; }
    public UserData data { get; set; }
}


[Serializable]
public class UserData
{
    public String firstName { get; set; }
    public String lastName { get; set; }
}
```